# Maurice Blanchot's view on death?

Tags: existentialism, continental-philosophy, phenomenology

Can someone please explain in simple terms what are the two types of death that Maurice Blanchot talked about? I came across an article about it on the Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy but I don't understand much since I'm a total beginner in philosophy...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can see Maurice Blanchot, [The Space of Literature (French ed 1955)](https://monoskop.org/images/9/94/Blanchot_Maurice_The_Space_of_Literature.pdf) : **Death as Possibility**.